# The assignment is to make a program that prompts the user for the size of 2 2D arrays and then multiplies them together

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, matrix

We must use functions, loops, data types, and pointers. I am honestly confused about pointers and how to use them in this context. I know they point to the memory address of a data type? I was wondering if maybe it would be possible to make the getElement function return a pointer to the array and then make the printArray function take a pointer as a parameter? would that work or is there a better way to do this.

Anyways this is what I have so far:

```c
    # include <stdio.h>
    
    void getElement(int[][]arr, int row, int column){
    
        for(int i=0; i< row;i++){
            for(int k = 0; k< column; i++){
    
                printf("Enter value for index [%i] [%i]: \n", i,k);
                scanf("%i", arr[i][k]);
            }
        }
    
    }
    void printArray(int **arr, int row, int column){
    
        printf("\nOutput Matrix:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j) {
                printf("%d  ", arr[i][j]);
                if (j == column - 1)
                    printf("\n");
          }
    }
    
    
    int main(){
    
        int mat1[10][10],mat2[10][10],result[10][10], r1,r2,c1,c2;
    
        printf("Enter rows and colums for first array: ");
        scanf("%i %i",r1,c1);
    
        printf("Enter rows and colums for second array: ");
        scanf("%i %i",r2,c2);
    
        while (r1 != c2){
            
            printf("not doable, Enter value for rows and colums of first array ");
            scanf("%i %i",r1,c1);
            printf("Enter rows and colums for second array: ");
            scanf("%i %i",r2,c2)
        }
    
        }
    
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "would that work". Yes it would if you do it properly. Do you have a specific problem? Also, please decide whether you are coding C or C++ as they are different languages.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you master simple arrays before you attempt multidimensional arrays. Write a program that constructs an array, fills it with numbers, then prints it out; once that's working perfectly, you'll find this assignment much easier.